# vue-slick-carousel - how to disable click of prev/next arrow button

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-slick-carousel

I am following this [library](https://gs-shop.github.io/vue-slick-carousel/#/) for making slick.

This is my current layout
[image]

I want to disable the click methods for `arrow-left` and `arrow-right` button, while keeping the arrow here, so that it will not change slide or anything. How to do it?

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-matan-55c76?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@click.stop` to stop event propagation. See more about [Event Modifiers](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#event-modifiers).

```html
<VueSlickCarousel>
  ...
  <template #prevArrow>
    <button class="arrow-btn">
      <img
        src="@/assets/images/common/arrow-right.svg"
        alt="arrow-left"
        @click.stop>
    </button>
  </template>
  <template #nextArrow>
    <button class="arrow-btn">
      <img
        src="@/assets/images/common/arrow-right.svg"
        alt="arrow-left"
        @click.stop>
    </button>
  </template>
</VueSlickCarousel>
```

**Updates**

To disable click event from button (not only from img). You can do it with css:

```css
.arrow-btn {
  pointer-events: none;

  img {
    pointer-events: all;
  }
}
```

But why not we just add `@click.stop` to button instead of img?

The problem is [here](https://github.com/gs-shop/vue-slick-carousel/blob/master/src/SliderArrow.vue#L52-L58):

```js
...

arrow = this.prevArrow ? (
  this.prevArrow(option)[0]
) : (
  <button type="button" data-role="none" style="display: block;">
    Next
  </button>
)
...

mergeVNodeData(arrow, 'on', {
  click: () => {
   if (clickable) {
     this.$emit('arrowClicked', { message: this.type })
   }
  },
})
```

First it checks if you have passed the prevArrow slot, if so they will use your slot. If not, they will use the default button.

And either way, they will combine their default props/event handlers which include the 'click' event, meaning that your click will only be overridden.

Comment: not working. If I click the area between the arrow button and slick item, I can still change slide

Comment: @CCCC I update my answer.